# iTerm2 keeps switching desktops using dropdown

Tags: macos, iterm

I'm using multiple iTerm2 windows on different desktops on my El Capitan and It's irritating how it keeps switching desktops when using Quake-like drop-down termina. 
Steps to reproduce:

```
1) open iterm
2) close opened window
3) check that you can invoke drop-down terminal using hotkey
4) create new iterm2 console window and move it to new desktop
5) go back to desktop where you opened iterm2 for first time and invoke hotkey for drop-down terminal, then invoke hotkey again to close drop-down
```

Behavior:
When hotkey is invoked, iterm shows drop-down terminal, when you invoke it again to close it, it momentarily changes desktops to one where you have other window opened and than back to original desktop. This is really irritating.

Expected behavior:
When drop-down is invoked, it doesn't switch desktops regardless of whether other iterm2 windows are opened on different desktops.

Matthew

Comment: Essentially, you cannot spread apps to more than one Space & expect them to function as intended. Spaces just won't work that way. One Space, one app & it will behave.

Answer (score 5):

Select `Preferences -> Profiles -> Window -> Space: All Spaces` then `Quit iTerm` and it should work! Important to fully quit the app for the settings to save!

[image: Settings for it to work]

Comment: Hm doesn't help me. Still goes to a certain desktop for some reason

Comment: Seems that you need both Screen with Cursor and All Spaces active for this to work

Comment: @trainoasis in my case fixed by [enabling the "floating window" option](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/417784/how-to-avoid-iterm2-switching-screens-before-opening-hotkey-window?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 3):

In case you have an additional Hotkey Window profile, it is important that `Preferences -> Profiles -> Window -> Space: All Spaces` and `Preferences -> Profiles -> Window -> Screen with Cursor` is enabled for **both** profiles.

[image]

Otherwise, at least in my case with Build *3.4.19* of iTerm2, these settings seemed to have interfered with each other, and my Hotkey Window sometimes, and especially after resuming from sleep mode, then still caused the slide-in terminal to show on a different (virtual) desktop. And even with a glitch, that it disappeared after slide-in, so I had to press the hotkey a second time.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This, for some reason, fixes it! Thanks a bunch.