# How to avoid iTerm2 switching screens before opening hotkey window

Tags: iterm

I've configured a fullscreen hotkey window as follows

[image]

If I hit the hotkey when the current desktop is a native full screen app, before opening the hotkey window, the desktop is changed to the first, free (not fullscreen) desktop.

Is there a way to prevent that? I want terminal to just open as an overlay without the annoying desktop change animation.

Using iTerm2 Build 3.4.4

Comment: Do you need to set the middle drop down like this other answer - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/415036/409922 - i.e. to screen with cursor?

Comment: Nope. Does not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to make it a floating window so it can overlap fullscreen windows of other apps:
[image]

- [@gnachman](https://gitlab.com/gnachman/iterm2/-/issues/9621#note_559614115)

Comment: This is in Profiles -> Keys -> Configure Hotkey Window